# Как правильно выводить информацию пользователям c учетом локализации в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mvc

Здравствуйте,
Можете подсказать как правильно отправлять во view сообщения пользователям. Например: пользователь регистрируется, но он ввел уже существующий email, соответственно, пользователю нужно выдать сообщение что такой email уже существует. Я хотел бы вывести это сообщение с учетом локализации "@lang('messages.welcome')". Как грамотно это организовать, что контролер регистрации должен возвращать?
Заранее спасибо за информацию.

Answer (score 1):

У laravel исчерпывающая [документация](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization#overriding-package-language-files).
В проекте найди `laravel/resources/lang/` там добавляй папки с необходимыми локалями по аналогии с папкой `en`.
@lang('messages.welcome') будет возвращать значения в зависимости от текущей локали.
Задать ее можно через `url` либо хранить в сессии

```
Route::get('/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);
});
```

или

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $locale = session('locale');
    App::setLocale($locale);
});
```

Comment: У меня вопрос в другом. Как передать из контроллера строку с сообщением,и чтобы потом ее вывести, с учетом локализации

Answer (score -1):

Вроде немного разобрался, в случае чего можно возвращать во view или в request.

```
return back()->with('RegSuccess',trans('messages.ActivationDone'));
```

Comment: Так ее не обязательно передавать....локализация доступна и во вьюшке в том числе.

Comment: А подскажите как реализовать такой метод обработки? Как вью должна знать, что например, сейчас должно показаться сообщение "успешной регестрации"?

Comment: Ну я для такого рода потребностей использую вот такой пакет. https://github.com/codecourse/notify

Comment: Ну а он работает на основе одноразовой сессии, т.е можно в контроллере записать событие $request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!'); а во вью проверить есть ли оно @if(Session::has)